# Analytical continuation of $\zeta(s)$ at $\operatorname{Re}(s) = 0$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

$\underline{\smash{\textbf{Background:}}}$ It is a well-known fact that the original definition of the zeta function, namely $$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}
$$ is only defined when $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$. We can then extend the domain by redefining $$
\zeta(s) = \frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}}
$$ whenever $2^{1-s} \neq 1$. Here, $\eta(s)$ is the alternating zeta function, which converges for all $s$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.

Now we extend the domain even further to the entire complex plane without $\operatorname{Re}(s) = 1$ by using the symmetry identity $$
\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s),
$$ which holds for all $s$ in the strip $0< \operatorname{Re}(s)<1$ and defining the zeta function using this identity for $\operatorname{Re}(s) < 0$.

$\underline{\smash{\textbf{My question:}}}$ How can this analytical continuation be defined for $s$ with real part zero? Applying the last identity to such numbers define $\zeta(s)$ in terms of $\zeta(1-s)$, but $1-s$ has a real part equal to $1$. But we excluded these numbers in the definition (and first continuation) of the zeta function.

Comment: Actually, the expression $\frac{\eta(s)}{1-2/2^{-s}}$ is undefined when $2^{1-s}=1$.

Comment: Yes, but this restriction only occurs for complex numbers with real part 1. However I did point it out in my post @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: The first extension defines $\zeta(s)$ for $s=1+it$, $t\ne0$, doesn't it?

Comment: Formula 9.10 at https://www.nhn.ou.edu/~milton/p5013/zeta.pdf gives $\zeta(s)$ as a contour integral defined for all complex $s\ne1$. There's another exposition at https://desvl.xyz/2022/11/24/riemann-zeta-continuation/ See also https://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.02/zeta1.pdf and any number of other webpages.